# WordPress 3.2: Add TinyMCE Buttons to HTML Editing in press-this.php

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

When I choose "HTML" (instead of "Visual") for the editor in press-this.php I want the TinyMCE buttons to show up like they do when adding/editing a post via post.php.

For example, here's a clipped screen shot of the buttons available in post.php when "HTML" is active:

[image: buttons available when editing html]

How do I get those buttons to show when using press-this.php?

I think this has to be a simple change but I haven't found a simple answer.  I haven't written any plugins before so if that's the solution I'd like some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Using "HTML" mode in WordPress (whether you are in press-this or posts or pages) is mutually exclusive with having the TimeMCE buttons showing up.  Clicking "Visual" puts you in TinyMCE mode.  Clicking "HTML" turns off TinyMCE mode.

TinyMCE helps you write HTML even if you don't know how to write HTML (clicking the **B** button basically wraps the text you have selected with a `<strong></strong>` tag pair) .  If you don't know HTML or you want an editor to help you write it faster, use "Visual".  If you want to write the HTML yourself or you want to tweak the HTML output of TinyMCE, then use "HTML".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you know how to activate the buttons shown in the screenshot (above)?  I assume that those buttons are from TinyMCE but you've indicated that TinyMCE is not active in "HTML" mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that much into WordPress, but [here is a very neat HowTo](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) of Moxiecode (the enterprise behind tinymce) which decribes how to write an own plugin (it is not that difficult).